# Using type variables declared inside lopp, outside of it

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program in VS c#. The c# program is intended to compare two projects and write a summary to a text box with detail of how and if the project devices differs. This is working successfully, so the code inside the first if-statement works.

However, I want to add a "fail-safe" that writes a string if the devices I'm comparing doesn't exist in both projects (The second if-statement). And its here I run into some hiccups.

So I want to access the `Prim` and `Sec` variables, which represent the two projects, inside the FIRST `foreach` loop, so that I can pass them in the SECOND if-statement. But the problem is that they are declared inside the SECOND foreach- loop and I have not found a way to access them. So I turn to you guys for help!

Any input or help will be greatly appreciated.

I've tried declaring the variables as

```
    var Prim = (Device)null;
    var Sec = (Device)null;
```

Inside the FIRST foreach loop and passed them by reference inside the SECOND foreach loop.

e.g

```
foreach (Device devicePrimary in MyProject1.Devices)
{
    foreach (Device deviceSecondary in MyProject2.Devices)
    {
        Prim = devicePrimary.DeviceItems[1].ToString();
        Sec = deviceSecondary.DeviceItems[1].ToString();

        if (Prim == Sec && Prim != null && Sec != null)
        {
            var leftDevice =devicePrimary.DeviceItems[1] 
                                .GetService<SoftwareContainer() 
                                .Software as PlcSoftware;

            var rightDevice = deviceSecondary.DeviceItems[1] 
                                .GetService<SoftwareContainer>()                                      
                                .Software as PlcSoftware;

            var Res = leftDevice.CompareTo(rightDevice);

            WriteResult(Res.RootElement, "");
        }
    }

    if( Prim != Sec)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Device does not exist in both projects.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just declare them outside the for loops

Comment: Aside: I could be off base but it makes me suspicious that you're only interested in the second element in the `DeviceItems` arrays.

Comment: What is a lopp?

Answer (score 2):

Just declare them in the first loop.

```
foreach (Device devicePrimary in MyProject1.Devices)
{
    string Prim = String.Empty;
    string Sec = String.Empty;
    foreach (Device deviceSecondary in MyProject2.Devices)
    {
      //your code
    }
    if( Prim != Sec)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Device does not exist in both projects.";
    }
}
```

You dont need the "ref" keyword to use these variables inside the second loop.

Comment: And you depend on luck if the last `deviceSecondary` matches? Else you would get invalid results. How are you solving that? The essential part of the code is left out.

Comment: op asked how he could access Prim and Sec in first and second loop and I answered that question

Comment: CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Siemens.Engineering.HW.Device'

cause I'm comparing the devices in the project based on names. The intended use of this program is to mainly compare different versions of the same project. And thus have to have the same device-names.

Comment: It's because if you define Prim and Sec as "Device", you cant do `Prim = devicePrimary.DeviceItems[1].ToString();` since they are "Device" and not "string"
If you just want the string part to work, then define them as "string" in the first loop. I've edited my answer to match the string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rewrite your program:

```
foreach (Device devicePrimary in MyProject1.Devices)
{
    var deviceSecondary = MyProject2.Devices.FirstOrDefault(ds => devicePrimary == ds);

    if (deviceSecondary != null)
    {
        // found
        var leftDevice =devicePrimary.DeviceItems[1] 
                            .GetService<SoftwareContainer() 
                            .Software as PlcSoftware;

        var rightDevice = deviceSecondary.DeviceItems[1] 
                            .GetService<SoftwareContainer>()                                      
                            .Software as PlcSoftware;

        var Res = leftDevice.CompareTo(rightDevice);

        WriteResult(Res.RootElement, "");
    }
    else
    {
        // not found
        textBox1.Text = "Device does not exist in both projects.";
    }
}
```

For your actual question: `Prim` should have a type, like `string Prim`. But then still you can't reference it outside the `foreach`, which will give a lot of other problems.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things.

1) `ref` isn't a type, so you can't declare an object as `ref`

2) In the second loop, you declare `Prim` and `Sec` as a string.  However, they are initialized as `(Device)null`.  If you want them as a string you need to initialize them as strings.  If you want them as `Device`s remove the `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

use a control variable so that while the second array is being traversed, it can store if the device is inside

```
foreach (Device devicePrimary in MyProject1.Devices)
{
    var deviceFound = false
    foreach (Device deviceSecondary in MyProject2.Devices)
    {
        Prim = devicePrimary.DeviceItems[1].ToString();
        Sec = deviceSecondary.DeviceItems[1].ToString();

        if (Prim == Sec && Prim != null && Sec != null)
        {
            var leftDevice =devicePrimary.DeviceItems[1] 
                                .GetService<SoftwareContainer() 
                                .Software as PlcSoftware;

            var rightDevice = deviceSecondary.DeviceItems[1] 
                                .GetService<SoftwareContainer>()                                      
                                .Software as PlcSoftware;

            var Res = leftDevice.CompareTo(rightDevice);

            WriteResult(Res.RootElement, "");
        }

        if( Prim == Sec)
        {
            deviceFound = true;
        }
    }

    if(!deviceFound)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Device does not exist in both projects.";
    }else{
        deviceFound = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only alert if last Device doesn't exist in both projects.